# How to compare two java collections of lists of strings with least code?

Tags: java, collections, compare

I have two lists of lists of strings. Say,

- List1: Element1: Tom, Hardy, nineteen, student;
  Element2: John, Travolta, twenty, unemployed;
- List2:
  Element1: John, Travolta, twenty, unemployed;
  Element2: Tom, Hardy, nineteen, student;

I want to compare these lists, and get the result that the lists are identical.
I could create a class "Person" with fields name, surname, age, occupation. Then create objects. But these lists come from different sources, so, the element objects would not be the same. I mean Element1 from List1 (Tom Hardy) would not be the same object as Element2 from List2 (Tom Hardy). I would have to go into each element's (object's) values and compare them to know if the lists are identical.
Basically, I know how to solve this, I just wondering how this can be done with least code.

Comment: Sort into some canonical order and then compare: ```Collections.sort(list1); Collections.sort(list2); result = list1.equals(list2);```  -- you might have to make copies if you don't wish to reorder the lists.   Assumes, of course, that your 'element'  class implements a useful ```equals``` method.

Comment: These don't look like lists of Strings to me; these look like lists of some  'element' type, which contains strings (and maybe other types - are you really storing 'age' as a string?)

Comment: The right way to compare the elements would be to implement the Object.equals method and use it to check all the necessary properties or conditions for equality. Don't forget, when you implement the equals method, you also need the hashCode method. Once the element comparison is ok, you can use List.containsAll to check if they have the same elements. Or, since the order doesn't matter, consider using Sets instead of Lists and comparing them with oneSet.equals(otherSet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least code solution I came up:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<String>> list1 = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("Tom", "Hardy", "nineteen", "student"),
            Arrays.asList("John", "Travolta", "twenty", "unemployed"));

    List<List<String>> list2 = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("Tom", "Hardy", "nineteen", "student"),
            Arrays.asList("John", "Travolta", "twenty", "unemployed"));

    List<String> thesePeople = separatePropertiesToBigSinglePropertySortedList(list1);
    List<String> thosePeople = separatePropertiesToBigSinglePropertySortedList(list2);
    System.out.println("sortedListsAreEqual = " + thesePeople.equals(thosePeople));
}

private static List<String> separatePropertiesToBigSinglePropertySortedList(List<List<String>> listWithSeparateProperties) {
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (List<String> propertiesOfPerson : listWithSeparateProperties) {
        String bigSingleProperty = "";
        for (String property : propertiesOfPerson) {
            bigSingleProperty = bigSingleProperty + property;
        }
        resultList.add(bigSingleProperty);
    }
    Collections.sort(resultList);
    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would define a `Person` class to hold the parts of data.

On that class you declare it to implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, with a `compareTo` method performing whatever work you consider to judge two persons as being equal.

You would then collect these `Person` objects into the various [lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

Lastly, compare lists by calling their [`List::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, which in turns calls `equals` on each element corresponding to each list.

> I want to compare these lists, and get the result that the lists are identical.

That is the job of [`List::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

> I could create a class "Person" with fields name, surname, age, occupation. Then create objects.

Yes. And implement the `compareTo` & `equals` & `hashCode` methods. Tip: See the [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) class.

> But these lists come from different sources, so, the element objects would not be the same. I mean Element1 from List1 (Tom Hardy) would not be the same object as Element2 from List2 (Tom Hardy). I would have to go into each element's (object's) values and compare them to know if the lists are identical.

Not quite sure what you mean here. Is it that the lists might have objects representing the same persons yet in a different order? That is a problem for `List::equals` which considers same order to be a condition of lists’ equality.

Two solutions:

- Write your own equality-testing utility to search the second list for each item in the first, after first checking that both lists have the same size.
- Sort. Call [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) on both lists before calling `List::equals`. If you want to preserve their current order, copy each list into new `List` objects; this is fast, as the element objects are not copied, only the references to those element objects are copied.

I recommend the second option, not the first.

> Basically, I know how to solve this, I just wondering how this can be done with least code.

Just do it. Write the `Person` class and `compareTo` & `equals` & `hashCode` methods.

No issue of "least code", here just comparing fields. Using the new functional features of Java with lambda syntax can shorten the code. But short code should *not* be your goal if you are learning Java. Writing out the code without lambdas will likely be longer but may help you better understand what is going on.

Do internet search to find *many* examples of `compareTo`.

Something like the following `Person` class. Notice how, in *my* interpretation, I omit `occupation` from consideration of equality and comparison. The business rules decided by a manager, not the whims of the programmer, dictate the meaning of `equals` and `compareTo`. By the way, remember that [`hashCode` *must* match the logic of `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20hashcode%20equals).

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Person implements Comparable < Person >
{
    // Statics
    private static final Comparator < Person > NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR =
            Comparator
                    .comparing( Person :: getDateOfBirth )
                    .thenComparing( Person :: getGivenName )
                    .thenComparing( Person :: getSurname );

    // Members
    private String givenName, surname;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String occupation;


    // Constructor
    public Person ( String givenName , String surname , LocalDate dateOfBirth , String occupation )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( givenName );
        Objects.requireNonNull( surname );
        Objects.requireNonNull( dateOfBirth );
        Objects.requireNonNull( occupation );
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    // `Comparable` interface
    public int compareTo ( Person other )
    {
        return NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR.compare( this , other );
    }

    // `Object` overrides

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Person person = ( Person ) o;
        return getGivenName().equals( person.getGivenName() ) &&
                getSurname().equals( person.getSurname() ) &&
                getDateOfBirth().equals( person.getDateOfBirth() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getGivenName() , getSurname() , getDateOfBirth() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person{" +
                "givenName='" + this.getGivenName() + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + this.getSurname() + '\'' +
                " | dateOfBirth=" + this.getDateOfBirth() +
                " | occupation='" + this.getOccupation() + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


    // Accessors

    public String getGivenName ( )
    {
        return givenName;
    }

    public String getSurname ( )
    {
        return surname;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth ( )
    {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getOccupation ( )
    {
        return occupation;
    }

    public int age ( ZoneId zoneId )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( zoneId );
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
        Period period = Period.between( this.getDateOfBirth() , today );
        return period.getYears() ;
    }
}
```

And some example usage.

We have two lists with same objects but different order. We compare them as-is and after sorting. For convenience of the programmer we use streams to do the sorting. Note that streams may be slower than conventional approaches, but not likely enough to be an issue.

```
List < Person > thesePeople = List.of(
        new Person( "Tom" , "Hardy" , LocalDate.of( 1984 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , "Student" ) ,
        new Person( "John" , "Travolta" , LocalDate.of( 1965 , Month.MARCH , 17 ) , "Unemployed" )
);

List < Person > thosePeople = List.of(
        new Person( "John" , "Travolta" , LocalDate.of( 1965 , Month.MARCH , 17 ) , "Unemployed" ),
        new Person( "Tom" , "Hardy" , LocalDate.of( 1984 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , "Student" )
);

boolean givenListsAreEqual = thesePeople.equals( thosePeople );
boolean sortedListsAreEqual = thesePeople.stream().sorted().collect( Collectors.toList() ).equals( thosePeople.stream().sorted().collect( Collectors.toList() ) );

System.out.println( "givenListsAreEqual = " + givenListsAreEqual );
System.out.println( "sortedListsAreEqual = " + sortedListsAreEqual );
```

> givenListsAreEqual = false
>
> sortedListsAreEqual = true

By the way, you'll see I store the date-of-birth. Storing an age makes no sense as the age may change day-to-day. I have `age` method to return a computed value.

Comment: your answer is very elaborate. Maybe even too much, eg notes about bussiness logic, like age and occupation. Nevertheless, your example with `toString` method gave me an idea, that I can simply concate all properties of a person into one. Then sort main lists, and finally compare them. Thanks for that.

Comment: @lucasso FYI: On Stack Overflow, you are encouraged to post your own Answer. Mark it as *accepted* if it best solves the Question.